# Canon MP495 Scanner with Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, drivers, 20.04, scanner, canon

**Problem:**

Each time I set up a fresh (new) Ubuntu, I struggle to get my **MP495** to work.

- With **Ubuntu 18.04** the printer finally works right out of the box but the scanner did not.
- With **Ubuntu 20.04** the printer setup UI led me into an endless loop (install<->select).

**What I tried so far:**

- installing *Simple Scan* (preferred tool) => no scanner found
- downloading the official *Linux IJ Scanner Driver* => unmet dependencies
- trying to install the canon scangearmp driver manually, e.g. with [this](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/14/canon-printer-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-16-04/) tutorial => impossible

**How can I get my scanner installed to simply use it with Simple Scan?**

Answer (score 5):

Canon MP495 for Ubuntu 20.04:

- For the printer:

  ```
  sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
  ```

  in gnome settings printers chapter select **Canon MP490 series gutenprint**
- For the scanner:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install scangearmp2
  sudo apt install scangearmp-mp495series
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've got to test it on my 20.04 system - and will accept it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

*After a couple of hours almost messing up my system and cleaning it up again I found a too simple solution which I share here for others and myself to find it in the future:*

- Install *Xsane* via *Ubuntu Software*
- Start *Xsane* and restart the printer, connect the scanner
- xsane automatically installed the scanner and was able to scan
- install *Simple Scan*, start and scan
- remove *Xsane*

If the scanner is not found, try to restart it and reconnect it to another USB port (weird, I know -.-). Maybe the whole *Xsane* stuff was not even necessary, I'll update this answer when I next reinstall the operating system. Feel free to comment if you were able to reproduce this or not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - it worked without a driver on Debian Bullseye!

Answer (score 0):

The sane library from very old ubuntu (14.04) works with this printer. I have to run a small docker container for ubuntu 14.04 for that reason. Just install minimum ubuntu 14.04 and install xsane which would pull the dependencies.

It is sad that the sane project did not hear bug report and address this driver at all after many bug reports.

UPDATE:

As of now with ubuntu 18.04 I did

add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
apt install cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 cndrvcups-utility
usermod -aG lpadmin

logout and re-login

Use firefox to access http://localhost:631 and search for new printer and add it.

Run xsane and try to scan.

Suprisingly the scan is OK.

However printing got crash from process cnijlgmon3. with SIGSEGV in __libc_start_main() :(

UPDATE AGAIN.

So much for a old printer with bad support form vendor!. I actually make it works using docker and debian wheezy which is the only distro that has libtiff4 and repository still works as of this time.

So spawn a container using this https://hub.docker.com/r/dockette/wheezy/ and run

```
apt-get install cups sudo libxrandr2
```

then run the installer from [canon support](https://www.canon.com.au/printers/pixma-mp495/support). It will auto detect and add the printer. It does work.
then

make /opt/start-print-server.sh with

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /var/run/dbus
dbus-daemon --system
avahi-daemon -D
exec cupsd -f
```

commit into an image eg. `debian-wheezy:mp495`

Run

```
docker run -d --restart always --entrypoint /opt/start-print-server.sh -v /run/cups:/run/cups --name debian-wheezy -v (pwd):/work --net host  --privileged debian-wheezy:mp495
```

Comment: Thanks for the protocoll ;-) I'll make sure to check it out as soon as I have to set up my printer again :-)